# MINGW64 (downloaded from www.git-scm.com) - How can I set it to use my system version of vim, rather than the build in version?

Tags: windows, terminal, vim, git

I'm trying to set up vim as a GO IDE. 
I also use the version of MINGW64 that git ships with as my terminal. 
Everything works as expected. I can run gvim from the terminal no problem, but when I try to run vim MING64 launches the version of vim it ships with, which is not Lua compatible.
How can I set MING64 to use my system version of vim instead of it's own version?

Comment: Put yours first in the `PATH`.

Comment: That doesn't work. I still get vim without lua support

Comment: You can try :set path+=thefullpathofsystemversion in ~/.vimrc  and open any vim and give :verbose set path. If the path you entered is not shown, then it is overridden by system.